# Keep the website background still

Tags: language-agnostic

In http://twitter.com/, when you scroll, the background image stays still, but only the main content at the center scrolls. How can this functionality be achieved? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a background image and set `background-attachment:fixed;`

look here for the css background property: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS property, `background-attachment: fixed;`

See http://www.symbols.net/webhelp/backgroundnoscroll/

Answer (score 1):

1. If you use "Frontpage" then when you insert your background image, also click on "Watermark."  This codes in the HTML to make the background fixed.
2. Or...after your background image HTML  insert this:

`background="fixed"` or

`bg properites="fixed"` or

```
<body background="xxx.jpg" behavior="fixed">
```

you can use [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) too:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color:#ffffff; 
background-image:url(URL_OF_YOUR_IMAGE); 
background-attachment:fixed;
}
</style>
```

Refrence:[link](http://www.brownielocks.com/fixedbackground.html)

Answer (score 0):

use CSS to position the background of your BODY tag in HTML.

```
body
{
background-image:url('still_image.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:right top;
}
```